# How to close main form without closing child forms?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have two forms named:

```
Form1 & Form2
```

In the **Form1** I have a button with this code in the button click event:

```
Form2.Show()
Me.Dispose()
```

When I click this button, it close both forms at the same time.

I only need to close the Form1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project settings are probably set to terminate the application when the startup form closes.  Changing the option to "last form closes" should fix this.

"Project" menu -> 'YourApp' Properties... -> Application Tab

find : "Shutdown Mode"

Change from "When startup form closes" --> "When last form closes"

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `Dispose` yourself. Try `Me.Close()` in the same context.

Comment: I've also tried Me.Close() and achievement have the same effect (Both are closed)